# Xcode how to stop right panel always opening when building iPad apps?

Tags: xcode

I'm running Version 5.0.1 (5A2053), and every time I click the play button to run my app on an iPad, the right panel opens.

It does not provide any value whatsoever to me, and after closing it ~200 times, **I'm interested if there's some Xcode 5.0.1 setting to prevent right panel from showing up when running apps on device.**

Sorry if this question is not very programming oriented, but it definitely adds a bit of frustration over time.

Comment: If my answer worked, do you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 14):

With the default preferences, it should not happen. If it is, then go to Xcode>Preferences>Behaviors, and on the left side, click into everything with a checkmark besides it.
[image]
There is a section on the right side that says `Show/Hide Utilities`. Uncheck it in every one you can. Don't do this in ones one the left without checks, because they already have that off by default. Hope this helps.

Edit: **Unchecking this flag in the "Starts" section fixed the issue:**
[image]